# Best Practice in Carbon format in laravel

Tags: laravel, date, format, php-carbon

What is the difference between

> Carbon::format('Y-m-d h:i:s')

and

> Carbon::format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
> in format?

Comment: The documentation on Carbon and PHP date formats already answers this: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

It displays the first hour as AM and PM

> like 6PM

But the second shows the clock as 24 hours

> like 18